# Creating a direction column based on logical conditions

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a financial time series dataset and I'm trying to create a new variable called Direction based on observations of the Rate of Return (RoR). Essentially, if the current RoR is higher than the previous days RoR, the direction would be "Up" and if it's lower, "Down".

I'm pretty sure I could combine for loops with ifelse to create the variable but I'm fairly new to R and I can't think of a way to write code that would lead to the desired output. I was able to create the variable I want in excel using the function: IF(G4>G3,"Up",IF(G4=G3,"No Change","Down")) but I don't know how to translate this function into R code

Are there any packages I could use, if not what code would lead to the desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `diff` with `sign` assuming `df` is your dataframe and `ROR` is the column name.

```
df$direction <- c(NA, c("Down", "No change", "Up")[sign(diff(df$ROR)) + 2])
```

Using an example

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1)
c(NA, c("Down", "No change", "Up")[sign(diff(x)) + 2])
#[1] NA          "Up"        "Up"        "Up"        "Down"      "No change" "Down"
```

---

Or we can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(direction = case_when(ROR > lag(ROR) ~ "Up", 
                           ROR < lag(ROR) ~ "Down", 
                           ROR == lag(ROR) ~ "No change",
                           TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```